# Radius of convergence in a series. Ratio test.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am having a hard time with this question.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{-(1)^k (4^k -3)x^{2k}}{k^4+3}$$

I used the ratio test and got stuck here:
$$x^2 \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(4^{k+1}-3)(k^4+3)}{((k+1)^4+3)(4^k-3)}$$

Im not sure how to simplify it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(4^{k+1}-3)(k^4+3)}{((k+1)^4+3)(4^k-3)}=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(4^{k+1}-3)}{(4^k-3)}\cdot \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(k^4+3)}{((k+1)^4+3)}$$
as long as the two limits on the right hand side exist. But,
 $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(4^{k+1}-3)}{(4^k-3)}=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(4-3/4^k)}{(1-3/4^k)}=4$$
and
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(k^4+3)}{((k+1)^4+3)}=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {(1+3/k^4)}{((1+1/k)^4+3/k^4)}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{4^{k+1}-3}{4^k-3}=\frac{4-\frac{3}{4^k}}{1-\frac{3}{4^k}}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}4\ldots 
$$